# Recuperando valores de lista de listas em python

Tags: python, array, python-3.x, numpy

Já tentei várias coisas e ainda não consegui captar qual o problema do meu código, é um código simples. Com *numpy* eu coloco os valores do txt no array de arrays e quero fazer algumas cópias para duas outras listas, `mensagem` e `no`.

```
    import numpy as dados
    i=0
    filename = input("Entre com o arquivo de dados:")

    entrada = dados.genfromtxt(filename, delimiter="    ", dtype=int)

    mensagem  = dados.zeros((300,1))
    no = dados.zeros((300,1))

    for x in range(0,entrada.shape[0]):
         if(entrada[x][0] in mensagem):
              print("JÁ")   
         else:
              mensagem[i]=(entrada[x][0])
              no[i]=(entrada[x][1])
              i=i+1

    arquivo = open('mensagem.txt', 'w')
    arquivo1 = open('no.txt', 'w')

    for x in range(0,300):
         arquivo.write(str(mensagem[x]))
         arquivo.write('\n')
    for x in range(0,300):
         arquivo1.write(str(no[x]))
         arquivo1.write('\n')
```

Já tentei mudar `dtype` para `int`, `float`, `None`.
Sempre a lista `no` recebe em poucas posições o valor correto, e o restante preenche com número 1.

Vale dizer que meu arquivo de dados que preenche a lista é do formato:

```
    2.94946 14  5
    2.92017 14  8
    2.9751  14  19
    2.97217 14  17
    2.88794 14  2
    2.95166 14  13
    2.87769 14  12
    2.95166 14  5
    2.95166 14  7
    2.88354 14  21
    2.94653 12  24
    2.99927 12  25
```

e possui mais de 300 mil linhas.

Alguma sugestão, ou notou algo errado?

Comment: seu arquivo é delimitado por espaços ou por tabs? as linhas começam mesmo com espaços como no seu exemplo?

Comment: Olá sergiopereira, sim, são demitados por tabs...2.94946TAB14TAB5

Comment: mudar o delimiter para \t não fez diferença :/

Comment: Acho que encontrei seu problema. Veja minha resposta.

Answer (score 2):

O que eu acho que está acontecendo é que, do jeito que você escreveu, seus dados estão sendo importados como strings.

Você também definiu `mensagem` e `no` como bidimensionais, onde cada elemento é um vetor separado. Aí, nessa linha...

```
no[i]=(entrada[x][1])
```

...você tenta atribuir uma de suas colunas (um valor `string`, como `"14"`) a um vetor. Como strings se comportam como vetores de caracteres, você termina com `no[i] = ['1', '4']`. Eu acredito que você estivesse tentando criar um `tuple` de 1 elemento. Para fazer isso você precisa adicionar uma vírgula para distinguir o `tuple` de parênteses desnecessários:

```
no[i]=(entrada[x][1],)
```

De toda forma, para mim funcionou com:

```
# importando com os defaults do numpy. Os valores serão tratados como floats
entrada = dados.genfromtxt('import-numpy-data.txt')

# depois, mais embaixo, a vírgula que falei
no[i] = (entrada[x][1],)

# no final, na hora de salvar, você precisa extrair o elemento 0 de
# cada linha
arquivo1.write(str(no[x][0]))
```

Com essas mudanças meu resultado usando os dados que você passou ficou assim

```
14.0
14.0
14.0
14.0
14.0
14.0
14.0
14.0
12.0
12.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
...o resto é tudo 0.0 ...
```